# does Kafka auto commit is sync or async under the hood?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If kafka `enable.auto.commit=true` 
does it mean that every 5 seconds it will trigger under the hood the sync or async operation for committing the offset?

can small interval(2 seconds) somehow influence latency?

Comment: maybe these can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546489/how-does-kafka-consumer-auto-commit-work?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546174/kafka-consumer-commitsync-vs-commitasync

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually uses both!

The "regular" auto commit that happens periodically when calling `poll()` using async. See [1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java#L358).

However, auto commit also happens when the consumer is closing or when joining a group and in these cases, it's using synchronous. See [2](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java#L452) or [3](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java#L560).

Regarding, auto commit using a low interval impacting latency, in most scenarios it's rather unlikely.