# What if a Kafka's consumer handles a message too long? Will Kafka reappoint this partition to another consumer and the message will doubly handled?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-partition

Suppose `Kafka`, `1 partition`, `2 consumers`.(2nd consumer is idle)

Suppose the 1st one consumed a message, goes to handle it with 3 other services and suddenly sticks on one of them and miss the Kafka's timeout.

Will Kafka reappoint the partition to the 2nd consumer and the message will doubly handled (suppose the 1st one eventually succeed)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What if a Kafka's consumer handles a message too long? Will Kafka reappoint this partition to another consumer and the message will doubly handled?

Yes, that's correct. If Kafka consumer takes too long to handle a message and **subsequent poll() is delayed**, Kafka will re-appoint this partition to another consumer and the message will be processed again (and again).

For more clarity, first we need decide and define 'How long is too long?'.

This is defined by the property `max.poll.interval.ms`. From the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.poll.interval.ms),

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

Consumer group is rebalanced if there are no calls to poll() within this time.

There is one more property `auto.commit.interval.ms`. The auto commit offsets check will be called only during the poll - it checks whether time elapsed is greater than the configured auto commit interval time and if result is yes, the offset is committed.

If Kafka consumer is taking too long to process the records, then the subsequent poll() call is also delayed and the offsets returned on the last poll() are not committed. If rebalance happens at this time, the new consumer client assigned to this partition will start processing the messages again.

Consumer group rebalance and resulting partition reassignment can be avoided by increasing this value. This will increase the allowed interval between polls and give more time to consumers to handle the record(s) returned from poll(). The consumers will only join the rebalance inside the call to poll, so increasing max poll interval will also delay group rebalances.

There is one more problem in increasing max poll interval to a big value. If the consumer dies for some other reason, it takes longer than the configured `max.poll.interval.ms` interval to detect the failure.

`session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms` are available in this case to detect the total failure as earlier as possible.

For more details about these parameters:

- Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730126/difference-between-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms-for-kafka-0-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)

Please note that the values configured for `session.timeout.ms` must be in the allowable range as configured in the broker configuration by properties

- group.min.session.timeout.ms
- group.max.session.timeout.ms

Otherwise, following exception will be thrown while starting consumer client.

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidSessionTimeoutException:
The session timeout is not within the range allowed by the broker
(as configured by group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms)
```

**Update: To avoid handling the messages again**

There is another method in KafkaConsumer class `commitAsync()` to trigger commit offsets operation.

```java
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
kafkaConsumer.commitAsync();
```

For more details on commitSync() and commitAsync(), please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546174/kafka-consumer-commitsync-vs-commitasync/48264461)

Committing an offset manually is an action of saying that the offset has been processed so that the Kafka won't send the committed records for the same partition again. When offsets are committed manually, it is important to note that if the consumer dies before processing records for any reason, there is a chance these records won't be processed again.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear. Are there any ways to avoid second handling?

Comment: @J.J.Beam updated answer with links and sample